I need to fill CMU block cores with grout
How much Portland cement and sand do I need to make 4 CY of grout to fill CMU cores?

Is CY cubic yards.  If so a cement truck might be the best idea.

Agree with crip, you are not mixing 4 cubic yards by hand.   Even Schwarzenegger would be exhausted doing that.

Yeah, 4 cubic yards sounds like a lot. How many blocks/how big a wall/structure is this?

A power mixer is indeed advisable. None of the grout specifications appear to give an expected volume of the completed mix, though I'd guess it's pretty close to the volume of the sand alone. i.e. standard mix of half a cubic foot (which is half a standard bag) of cement (with optional 0-0.05 CF lime putty) to 1.5 CF of damp sand for the ASTM C476-10 spec likely does not yield 2 CF mixed, as most of the cement ends up between the sand particles. So likely 4 CY sand and 36 bags of cement comes out really close, though you can also buy a dry cubic yard 3000lb bag of pre-mix to mix on site.

4 CY is nearly half a concrete truck worth...

A pallet of concrete mix like Sakrete or Quickcrete, is one cubic yard, 42 bags 80 lbs each in each pallet.
The cost, when I figured it one time was about the same ordering it from a concrete company that will deliver it, and you will not break your back mixing it by hand.

Concrete mixers do exist. Depending on the details of the project, using a small mixer on-site may be far more cost-effective than ready-mix and a pumper truck to get the stuff into the wall cores.

@Ecnerwal , I gave that some thought. Yes there mixers for rent, that would save a large part of the back breaking work, but it would still end up in a wheelbarrow to get it where it needs to go. The same could be done with a delivery of ready mix grout. To add more about the task itself for the OP, the CMU walls need to be damp so when the grout start going in, the otherwise dry walls will suck all the moisture out of the grout right away. This will have the grout block its own path going into the CMU. The wait between mixing batches will make that even worse.
